# don't want to automatically add "@" symbol in excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-365

I am adding a formula using VBA in a excel cell and excel automatically adding a "@" symbol after the "=" sign.

this is the vba code.

[image]

It is putting the whole string as formula but also adds the @ symbol and the formula didn't expand.

[image]

But if I manually remove the @ then the formula works as expencted.

[image]

Sorry for not adding screenshots using basic example.

How to tackle this problem. How to remove this "@" symbol using vba ??? And what is the function of this symbol?

Comment: Use `.Formula2` instead. As to what it is see: https://superuser.com/questions/1525270/why-have-at-symbols-suddenly-appeared-in-my-excel-formulae/1525279#1525279

Comment: Please don't use image instead of code, but copy the plain text. And here, the code is truncated... I guess `Offset`, but what is missing afterwards ? Use backtics (`) to print code as code.

Comment: `.Formula` will return a single formula in a single cell, so the only way for Excel to do that is to use the implicit intersection (`@`).  If you want it to spill you need to tell Excel that is what you want and why you need `.Formula2`.  Just like if you want to enter an array formula you must use `.FormulaArray` .